# What is SQL Server "Denali"? What's new?

Tags: features, sql-server-2012

I found a new title called **SQL Server "Denali"** in the drop down list on MSDN, but I didn't find much information about it:

- [What's New](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500435%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) (this documentation is for preview only as I see)
- [Top 9 New Features of SQL Server "Denali"](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3916166/Top-9-New-Features-of-SQL-Server--Denali.htm)

Does anyone have more detailed information about **new features** or significant **bug fixes** in this release? I'm hoping someone has used or tested it.

## New Features

- [Sequences](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dev/sequence_sql_server_2011_p1.aspx)
- [Extended FILESTREAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) (thanks to [Eric Humphrey](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/736/is-it-better-to-store-images-in-a-blob-or-just-the-url/741#741))
- [OFFSET & FETCH (ORDER BY Clause)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385(v=SQL.110).aspx)
- [Memory Manager Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlosteam/sql-server-memory-manager-changes-in-denali)
- [LAG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)(..) and [LEAD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)(..) .. OVER (Partition By..Order By) clause (thanks to [gbn](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/401/what-is-sql-server-denali-whats-new/7035#7035))
- [Aaron's list](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14731/81)

Comment: Aaron also posted [a great list here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14731/2660).

Comment: certainly if it's too broad to ask where a database violates a spec, it's too broad to ask what a database provides that's "new"

Comment: @EvanCarroll While there are some questions that would get closed today, I don't think we should be actively closing existing questions that were apparently useful "back when" (judging by the number of votes).

Comment: Questions aren't judged by usefulness but by the ideology of an elite few.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The new features include :

- Multi-Subnet Failover Clustering
- Programming Enhancements including sequences, ad-hoc query paging and full-text search tweaks
- BI and Web Development Environment Improvements
- Web-based Visualization
- Data Quality Services enhanced

You can view the detailed review here :  [New Features Of Denali](http://newtech.about.com/od/databasemanagement/a/Sql-Server-2011-Denali.htm)

"Denali" is a code name. Here is the list of the code name of other versions of SQL Server:

- 1993 – SQL Server 4.21 for Windows NT
- 1995 – SQL Server 6.0, codenamed SQL95
- 1996 – SQL Server 6.5, codenamed Hydra
- 1999 – SQL Server 7.0, codenamed Sphinx
- 1999 – SQL Server 7.0 OLAP, codenamed Plato
- 2000 – SQL Server 2000 32-bit, codenamed Shiloh (version 8.0)
- 2003 – SQL Server 2000 64-bit, codenamed Liberty
- 2005 – SQL Server 2005, codenamed Yukon (version 9.0)
- 2008 – SQL Server 2008, codenamed Katmai (version 10.0)
- 2010 – SQL Server 2008 R2, Codenamed Kilimanjaro (aka KJ)
- 2011 – SQL Server 2012, Codenamed Denali

Comment: @vettipayyan : semma username:)

Answer (score 9):

## [AlwaysOn High Availability and Disaster Recovery](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlalwayson/archive/2010/12/06/introducing-sql-server-code-name-denali-alwayson.aspx)

If you're interested in the extra disaster recovery stuff that is included with Denali, there was a useful series of articles on Microsoft's CSS blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/tags/alwayson/

Additional resources:

- [SQL Server AlwaysOn Team Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlalwayson/)
- [Brent Ozar's introduction to AlwaysOn](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/11/sql-server-denali-database-mirroring-rocks/)

Comment: Personally, I am really excited about the AlwaysOn Availability Groups.  On paper, it will make Database Mirroring on interrelated databases much less of a pain.

Answer (score 8):

[LAG and LEAD](http://sqlandme.com/2011/07/28/sql-server-denali-analytic-functions-lag-and-lead/) (Blog article) and the other [OVER clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28SQL.110%29.aspx) (MSDN) stuff.

And [these blog articles](http://blog.waynesheffield.com/wayne/archive/tag/denali/) cover most of them

Comment: It was about time for those :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Columnstore Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492153%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088%28v=sql.110%29.aspx):

> Columnstore indexes group and store data for each column and then join all the columns to complete the whole index.

Notes:

- Tables with enabled columnstore indexes cannot be modified.

  Remus Rusanu recommends using **Denali's much higher limit on the number of partitions per table (new limit: 15,000; old limit: 1,000)** to [switch in new partitions of data without having to rebuild your columnstore indexes](http://rusanu.com/2011/07/13/how-to-update-a-table-with-a-columnstore-index/).
- SQL Server's storage mechanism is staying the same with Denali, and your table data will still be stored in a row-oriented fashion.

Comment: FYI you can also get 15K partitions in 2008 SP2 & 2008 R2 SP1 - so this isn't strictly a 2012 feature. I know you're talking about the combination of 15K & ColumnStore but I just wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 7):

## [IIF()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) and [CHOOSE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213019.aspx)

These are new switching functions that were once available only on [Microsoft Access](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/). They are syntactic sugar for `CASE` expressions and compile to the same plans (source: [IIF](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/09/10/sql-server-denali-logical-function-iif-a-quick-introduction/), [CHOOSE](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/09/11/sql-server-denali-logical-function-choose-a-quick-introduction/)).

### Syntax

```
IIF ( boolean_expression, true_value, false_value )
CHOOSE ( 1-based-index, val_1, val_2 [, val_n ] )
```

Note: Both these functions cast their output to the data type with the [highest precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx) from the set of types passed in as arguments.

### Examples

```
SELECT IIF(1 = 1, 'true', 'false') iif_example;
SELECT CHOOSE(3, 10.3354, 'It slices!', 1337, N'It dices!') choose_example;
```

Note how in the second example the output is `1337.0000`. That's because `10.3354` gets [implicitly cast](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6900/select-power10-0-38-0-throws-arithmetic-overflow-error/6941#6941) to `NUMERIC(8, 4)`, which has the highest data type precedence in the list of arguments passed to `CHOOSE()`. Thus, the output also get cast to `NUMERIC(8, 4)`, which is why you see four trailing zeros after the decimal.

Answer (score 5):

Its the codename for the next SQL Server engine..

The ctp can be downloaded at http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/future-editions.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/denali_resource_center.aspx

Articles/Blogs which have interesting links...

- [Link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-integration-services/bg-p/SSIS)
- http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2010/11/30/sql-server-denali-serverless-sql-server.aspx