# the best place for save binary file

Tags: database-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Files - in the database or not?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/files-in-the-database-or-not)

anyone can tell me, what is the best place for save binary file? database or just in a file system? and what is plus and minus for both? :D

actually, I want to save my image file, but I don't know what is the place for save my image

thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is similar to: [Files - in the database or not?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/2445/1469). Click the link to see the answers provided.