# store a file into table from TSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Files - in the database or not?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/files-in-the-database-or-not)

I Want to store a file into sql server 2008 from TSQL (Management Studio).
I Know the file saving into varbinary column can be done by using the .NET

But I want to do this from Management Studio.

In C# and VB.NET we saving file into varbinary column by using ReadAllBytes()

How I can achieve this in Management Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291255/insert-image-into-database

Please read about [File Stream](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.100).aspx) too.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer on this question

[Which is good Pratice storing a uploaded File in DB or storing it in Filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808624/which-is-good-pratice-storing-a-uploaded-file-in-db-or-storing-it-in-filesystem/2808683#2808683)

Guidelines for using filestream

[Filestream in Sql Server 2008 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795911/filestream-in-sql-server-2008-express/2801080#2801080)

**UPDATE:**

If you just need a solution to load a file in sql server and save it to a table, here're some approaches to achieve this

[SQL SERVER – Import CSV File Into SQL Server Using Bulk Insert – Load Comma Delimited File Into SQL Server](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/)

[Different Options for Importing Data into SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1207/different-options-for-importing-data-into-sql-server/)

[How To Store Any File into SQL Database](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36584/How-To-Store-Any-File-into-SQL-Database)

Here's a sample query

```
BULK
INSERT Test
FROM 'c:\test.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
SELECT *
FROM Test
```

Good Luck!