# Downloading image data type contain to desktop SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I am very new to SQL Server 2008 and question may look very basic to gurus.

Following in the problem universe.

1. I have a huge (600 GB size) SQL Server 2008 table that stores `pdf` files in a column of type `Image`
2. Need is to download all the images from database table to my desktop (not on to the server).
3. I can't run C#, ASP.NET etc in the environment and has to rely on SQL Server Management Studio for the job (I see a option called power shell but not sure how to use it)

Table looks like following

Table name : `Attachments`

Columns :

```
FileID (PK, int, not null)  
Owner (int, null)   
file_name (varchar(50), null)   
file_type (varchar(50), null)   
file_size (int, null)   
file_date (datetime, null)  
file_BIN (image, null)
```

Comment: Define *huge* - how many rows is that??

Comment: [*`ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Is SSIS an option?

Comment: Can the server directly access your computer (assuming you set up appropriate security permissions on your machine), or is there a firewall in place to prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366544/how-to-export-image-field-to-file) provides the following [Simple Talk article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/) with instruction and information on how to extract this data.  Unfortunately, there is no cut and dried method for natively converting this data because of the hurdles in storing this kind of data within a database table.

For more discussion on this practice and the issues surrounding it, I suggest you read [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/files-in-the-database-or-not).

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your update but I do not want to read from or write to the file stored in the table, but want to strip files to my desktop (prefer if possible) or to the server where SQL server is installed.

Comment: You're talking about the same thing.  You need to read the file from the database system, then write it to the file system.