# Is there a good reason to store big text data outside database?

Tags: mysql, database-design, optimization

I was analyzing my MySQL database performance and found that tables containing text fields are just huge, larger than 1Gb.

This data is only used when loading single record (like article or blog post) and is updated very rarely.

Is there a reason to save text data to plain files and metadata to database, or let the db engine handle it all?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to consider moving the data outside the database if:

- You are having problems with backup durations
- It causes disk or network throughput problems on your database server
- You have a requirement to access the data without using the database

In general, I'd suggest keeping it *in* the database unless you can come up with a good reason not to.

There's some overlap between this question and ["Files - in the database or not?"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/files-in-the-database-or-not). You might find some useful thoughts there, though things that are true for binary files don't necessarily hold true for text data.

MySQL offers some useful features where text is stored in the database, such as opportunities to use [full-text indexing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html), and [network compression](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/12/20/large-result-sets-vs-compression-protocol/).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of my inputs to stand "FOR OUTSIDE DB"

It purely depends upon your need. If your business wants to keep them always available and recoverable with no down time then you might have to think a proper option to keep them available 24/7, but keeping them in Database the capacity management of DB server will be in question.

If no priority for your need then I would say better to keep raw files in appserver, just the location of the file in DB server in terms of `varchar` would help and adding index to it would benefit to get the right file location quicker even the number of rows are more. Imagine you have each field consisting of 1GB text and for 100 rows the size of the table would go more than 100GB. Sounds weird for me when I need to take care of everything like how DB performs when it comes to time taken for recovering the Database in-case of shutdown / backup / High Availability and over all performance of DB server.

I haven't got an opportunity to design such a requirement. But if given

- I would keep them in app server as each files in file system.
- Keep the file locations in tables as `varchar`.
- Let the application logic to generate the file locations in the order of the design pattern you want according to your server
  infrastructure.
- Keep the raw file mount point hard link to another server with same file naming nomenclature, in-case of disaster of your files use the
  fail over server IP for the application to point.

By this way DB performance will look good, quick recovery and data availability 24/7 and less time spent in-case of any maintenance activities.