# Pulling an Image from a Database vs pulling from a link to a directory

Tags: mysql, query

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it better to store images in a BLOB or just the URL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/736/is-it-better-to-store-images-in-a-blob-or-just-the-url)
>   [Files - in the database or not?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/files-in-the-database-or-not)

I was wondering what the benefit is of pulling a varchar out of a database that refers to picture link to display to the user on a website is.  I am a working with a developer who insists that we store and pull the picture directly in the database using a clob.  It seems as though there is no appreciable difference.  Maybe I am just an idiot, but why do one over the other?

Thanks