# Can I optimize this MERGE statement?

Tags: sql-server, merge, optimization

I am attempting a single column merge between two tables. The first table (`VisitorSession`) has 40,000,000 rows. The second (`ShoppingCart`) has 9,000,000 rows.

In my development environment, the query takes just under 8 minutes. But in the production environment, it should take significantly less (much more powerful machine). However, I anticipate the query taking at least 2 minutes to run in production. I know that this query was causing timeouts for other developers in the development environment, which means it could easily cause timeouts for customers. Is there a safer and/or faster way to perform this query?

```
declare @dt datetime = cast(dateadd(month, -6, getdate()) as date);

merge ShoppingCart as TargetTable  -- 07:55 to complete in Dev
using 
(
  select * from -- 04:55 to run select, resulting in 12,727,927 rows in Dev
  (
    select
      visitorid  -- int, not null, foreign key
      ,useripaddress  -- varchar(55), null
      ,row_number() over 
      (partition by visitorid order by createdate desc) as [row]
    from VisitorSession (nolock)
    where UserIPAddress is not null
    and CreateDate > @dt   -- createdate is a datetime, not null
  ) as subTbl
  where subTbl.[row] = 1
) as SourceTable
on (TargetTable.VisitorID = SourceTable.VisitorID)  -- visitorid is not a primary key
when matched
  then update set
  TargetTable.UserIpAddress = SourceTable.UserIpAddress;
```

Comment: (1) you could use a normal `UPDATE` instead of a `MERGE`, no? (2) you could break it up into chunks (see [this blog post](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes) for an example using `DELETE`...

Comment: You might benefit from reading the following blog post of Paul White: [Optimizing T-SQL queries that change data](https://www.sql.kiwi/2013/01/optimizing-t-sql-queries-that-change-data.html).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Personally, I don't like `MERGE` because there are many unresolved bugs:

- [This blog post](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/02/t-sql-queries/another-merge-bug) (scroll down to "Other `MERGE` issues")
- [This answer by AlexKuznetsov](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14860/1186)
- These posts on [Paul White's blog](https://www.sql.kiwi/search?q=merge+bug)
- [I published a cautionary tip about `MERGE` here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/tip-on-using-caution-with-merge/), including references to several bugs that haven't been addressed.
- And this list may not even be exhaustive - given the number of bugs discovered by this small set of users, I have to wonder how many haven't been discovered yet?

`MERGE` also gives a false sense of security in terms of optimistic concurrency and race conditions. See [Dan Guzman's blog post](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx) for more details.

I'm not trying to be a fear-mongerer here. But I also find the syntax unintuitive and daunting. So I would only use it in cases where it's actually needed *and* I can prove that I'm not affected by *any* of the above issues. I don't know what I would ever possibly gain from using it for an operation that could only ever end in an `UPDATE` anyway.

So here is how I would do it instead, using syntax that is much more familiar to me:

```
;WITH s AS 
(
  SELECT VisitorID, UserIpAddress FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      VisitorID,
      UserIpAddress,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VisitorID ORDER BY CreateDate DESC)
    FROM dbo.VisitorSession
    WHERE UserIpAddress IS NOT NULL
    AND CreateDate > @dt
  ) AS x
  WHERE rn = 1
)
UPDATE c
  SET c.UserIpAddress = s.UserIpAddress
  FROM dbo.ShoppingCart AS c
  INNER JOIN s
  ON c.VisitorID = s.VisitorID;
```

You can also break this operation into chunks to reduce the impact on the transaction log which may, in turn, reduce the overall duration. [I blogged about this here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes).

Here is how I would handle that approach:

```
DECLARE 
  @dt DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, -6, SYSDATETIME()), 
  @rc INT = 1;

WHILE @rc > 0
BEGIN

  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  ;WITH s AS 
  (
    SELECT TOP (100000) VisitorID, UserIpAddress FROM
    (
      SELECT 
        VisitorID,
        UserIpAddress,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VisitorID ORDER BY CreateDate DESC)
      FROM dbo.VisitorSession AS s
      WHERE UserIpAddress IS NOT NULL
      AND CreateDate > @dt
      AND EXISTS
      ( 
        SELECT 1 FROM dbo.ShoppingCart AS c
          WHERE c.VisitorID = s.VisitorID
          AND (c.UserIpAddress <> s.UserIpAddress
          OR c.UserIpAddress IS NULL)
      )
    ) AS x
    WHERE rn = 1
  )
  UPDATE c
    SET c.UserIpAddress = s.UserIpAddress
    FROM dbo.ShoppingCart AS c
    INNER JOIN s
    ON c.VisitorID = s.VisitorID;

  SET @rc = @@ROWCOUNT;

  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```

Of course, as the blog post illustrates, you can gain just about as much time by making sure your log is big enough to handle the entire transaction without having to grow - most of the delay is likely coming from many, many autogrow operations accommodating your large transaction. Sadly until you've done the operation once it can be very difficult to try and guess how much transaction log you'll need...

Comment: Aaron, What do you think about using Merge in 2018?  Same?

Comment: @johnny Yep, same, in fact I updated [that post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) a few months ago. You can accomplish close to 100% of what merge does without it, so, why use it?

Comment: I don't know other than it looked like the "proper" tool, but I'd much rather use separate statements.  I figured I was just wrong to not use it and was reinventing the wheel instead of using Merge.

Answer (score 3):

I ran a test against [Aaron Bertrand's](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44069/24710) Common Table Expression (CTE).  The performance was nearly identical (07:56 for the CTE verses 07:55 for the merge--only testing once each).

Next, I attempted Aaron's chunk'ed statement (to prevent blocking).  However, I ran into an issue with grouping the records on every pass.  The performance dropped to unacceptable levels because of this constraint on a such a large table.  On the upside, his formulation gave me an idea on how to reduce the running time *and* avoid using MERGE.

Switching to a CTE was an easy choice.  By reducing the result set from the smaller joining table *first* (the one with 9,000,000 records), the total records required to join on, *and* update, reduced significantly.

```
/* results from shared development server:
    run #1:  00:52 with 193,379 rows affected
    run #2:  00:56 with 193,379 rows affected
    run #3:  02:19 with 193,379 rows affected
    run #4:  00:15 with 193,379 rows affected
    run #5:  01:59 with 193,379 rows affected
    run #6:  01:14 with 193,379 rows affected
*/
declare @dt datetime = cast(dateadd(month, -6, sysdatetime()) as date);

;with cte as (
    select distinct  -- 00:26, with 179,160 rows
        visitorid
    from ShoppingCart (nolock) sc
    where CreateDate > @dt
)
update ShoppingCart
set UserIpAddress = desired.UserIPAddress
from ShoppingCart
join (
    select *  -- 02:36 with 179,016 rows
    from (
        select
            vs.visitorid
            ,vs.useripaddress
            ,row_number() over
            (partition by vs.visitorid order by vs.createdate desc) as rownumber
        from visitorsession (nolock) vs
        join cte on vs.VisitorID = cte.VisitorID
        where vs.CreateDate > @dt
        and vs.UserIPAddress is not null
    ) as subTbl
    where rownumber = 1
) as desired on ShoppingCart.VisitorID = desired.VisitorID
where ShoppingCart.CreateDate > @dt;
```

Feeding a much smaller result set from the CTE into the sub-select for the UPDATE radically increased performance on the UPDATE.  Preserving the *6 month timeframe* constraint on each step also helped keep the result set smaller for SQL Server to optimize performance.  The final query typically runs for about *1 minute* in the development environment.  In production, this will most likely run in much less time, and I don't expect any requests to timeout with our current configuration.