# Using an Aggregate In Merge Update Statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, update, merge

I am attempting to run a `COUNT()` statement in an update statement.  However my syntax presents this error

```
Msg 157, Level 15, State 1, Line 6<br>
An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.
```

What do I need to change in my syntax so this statement will execute succesfully?

```
MERGE masterdata md
USING receivedData rd
ON md.empName = rd.empName
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET md.numberOfSales = COUNT(rd.SaleID);
```

Comment: Why are you even using MERGE here?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I am comparing two tables and if the empName matches then updating a field, if the empName does not exist in masterdata then I am inserting the new data.  Is MERGE not the route to go to perform this?

Comment: Usually not - that's still an UPDATE, what does MERGE buy you? (Well, aside from [other potential problems](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).)

Comment: Would it be better if I ran 2 statements then, one to update the matched and a second to insert the non matches, as opposed to one Merge Statement?

Comment: Thank you for that link, I was unaware of the issues that can be created.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - your current `MERGE` statement doesn't do anything with non-matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cant test this right now, but doing the aggregate in the USING clause should work:

```
MERGE INTO masterdata md
USING (
    SELECT empName, COUNT(SaleID) as CNT
    FROM receivedData
    GROUP BY empName
) rd
    ON md.empName = rd.empName
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET md.numberOfSales = rd.CNT;
```

One powerful aspect of the relational model is that it is closed under select, join, union and so forth. Closed in the sense that the result of a query is a relation (or table in SQL). Therefor it is easy to form new derived relations that can be used in place of a table.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you're using `MERGE` for this. This would normally just be an update with a join, but it is complicated because of the aggregate (I hope that `receivedData` is part of some ETL process and not permanent data; if it is the latter then you're just storing redundant data for no clear reason).

With transactional control and error handling set aside:

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT empName, c = COUNT(SaleID) FROM dbo.receivedData
)
UPDATE md SET numberOfSales = x.c
  FROM dbo.masterdata AS md
  INNER JOIN x
  ON x.empName = md.empName;

INSERT dbo.masterdata(empName, NumberOfSales)
  SELECT empName, COUNT(SaleID) 
  FROM dbo.receivedData AS r
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.masterdata
    WHERE empName = r.empName)
  GROUP BY empName;
```

`MERGE` may *look* like an easier way to solve this problem (though your question didn't talk about non-matches at all), but as I point out [in this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/), there are much bigger problems you need to be wary of.

See another more detailed answer that talks about this alternative to `MERGE` for this use case:

- [Can I optimize this MERGE statement?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44067/can-i-optimize-this-merge-statement/44069#44069)

Also please always [use schema names in all object references](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).

Also, be very careful about case - either your names are sloppy (master**d**ata vs. received**D**ata) or your code is, and [this can lead to problems too](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-careless-about-case).